# Opacity transition not working in both directions

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

I expected this to transition when entering *and* leaving the dimmed state but it only transitions when leaving. How can I make the transition work when entering it? I also tried `ease-in` and `ease-out` but these don't seem to make a difference.

```
.is-dimmed-unless-active:not(:active):not(:focus):not(:hover) {
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Live example of problem http://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/doKdgW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to define the `transition` on `.card`:

```
.card {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Instead on:

```
.is-dimmed-unless-active:not(:active):not(:focus):not(:hover) {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you css to this:

```
.is-dimmed-unless-active {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.is-dimmed-unless-active:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}

.card {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  color: crimson;
  border: 3px dotted crimson;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: white;
}
```